# Possible LuaLaTeX Problem (compilation seems to hang)

Tags: hyperref, luatex

I asked a question earlier, where I had problems with my font specification, since I am using LuaLaTeX with Caslon. I am on Win 7 with TeXLive 2013 (up to date).
The file compiles just fine with XeLaTeX.

Here is my preamble and the compiler seems to hang at this point of the output:

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,
% DIVcalc,
% BCOR12mm,
12pt]{scrartcl}
\linespread{1.6}
\usepackage{setspace}
% \singlespacing
% \onehalfspacing
% \doublespacing
%\setstretch{1.2} % for custom spacing
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\synctex=-1
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfcolmk}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\PassOptionsToPackage{normalem}{ulem}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{units} %for nicefrac
\usepackage{ftnxtra}



%%%XeTeX-font-modifications
 \usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \usepackage[rm]{titlesec}
 %\usepackage{titletoc}
 \usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
 \usepackage{polyglossia} 
 \usepackage{csquotes} 
 \setdefaultlanguage{english}
 %\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
 %\setmainfont[Numbers=Proportional,Ligatures=TeX]{Adobe Caslon Pro}
\setmainfont[
    Extension      = .otf,
    Ligatures      = TeX,
    BoldFont       = ACaslonPro-Bold,
    ItalicFont     = ACaslonPro-Italic,
    BoldItalicFont = ACaslonPro-BoldItalic
  ]{ACaslonPro-Regular}
 %\usepackage{luaotfload}


%%%for luatex
%\usepackage{uniinput-lualatex}
%\usepackage{luatextra}


%%%special typesetting adjustment
%\usepackage{microtype}

%\usepackage[english]{selnolig}


%%% Equations
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathcomp}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

% %%%XeTeX Mathfont  XITS Math
% \usepackage[MnSymbol]{mathspec}
% \setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)
% [Numbers={Lining,Proportional}]{Latin Modern Math}




%%% THE BIB
\usepackage[backend=biber,
citestyle=authoryear,bibstyle=philosophy-modern,
natbib=true,isbn=false,url=false,maxcitenames=2,language=english,hyperref=true,sorting =nyt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{draft.bib}

%%%geometry
\usepackage[lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2cm,bottom=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,includeheadfoot]
{geometry}



%%%Symbols
\usepackage{eurosym}


%%% TABLES
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}          
\usepackage{multicol}          
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{rotating} %zum drehen von Tabellen ins Querformat
\usepackage{dcolumn} % ???
\usepackage{enumerate}

%%% Grafiken
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning} 

%%% version control
\usepackage{mVersion}
\increaseBuild

%%%shaping
%\usepackage{shapepar}

%%% To-do-Notes
% \usepackage[german,textsize=footnotesize]{todonotes}
% \setlength{\marginparwidth}{4cm}
% \reversemarginpar %vorÃ¼bergehend, damit marginnotes Platz haben
% \setlength{\hoffset}{3cm}
% \setlength{\textwidth}{14cm} 

%def:stodo
% \newcommand{\stodo}[2][]
% {\todo[caption={#2}, size=\small, #1]{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}    {0.5}\selectfont#2\par}}

%%% Schusterjungenkontrolle
\widowpenalty=10000
\clubpenalty=10000

%%% Verzeichnisse


%%% Makros 
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}


%%% HYPERREF
\usepackage[english,linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks = true,
    linkcolor = blue,
    anchorcolor = blue,
    citecolor = blue,
    filecolor = red,
    urlcolor = blue
}
```

Here is where the compiler hangs:

```
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-philosophy/english-philosophy.lbx (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx)) (./draft.aux
) (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
(./draft.bbl)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(./draft.out) (./draft.out)
```

If you have any idea, why the compiler hangs please tell me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The file is hanging out? Sorry, I just had to post this... `:)`

Comment: Well done! But there is no badge for wordplay, or is there?

Comment: It is unrelated to reading the `.out` file, because this is finished, as can be seen by the closing parenthesis. `hyperref` reads the `.out` file in `\AtBeginDocument`, thus your document hangs there or later.

Comment: Package `pdfcolmk` does not make much sense. Nowadays pdfTeX and LuaTeX have color stacks. Also package `luacolor` exists for LuaLaTeX where the color is implemented based on LuaTeX's attributes.

Comment: BTW, I recommend to load package `bookmark` (after `hyperref`), because it improves the boomark management and provides new options (color, bold/italics, more action types).

Comment: Thank you very much for all these comments and hints, Heiko Oberdiek. I am trying to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: I suspect a bad bug in the last `luaotfload` release, because my LuaTeX hangs on the following document: `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{fontspec}`

Comment: Well, I had problems with luaotfload earlier, before I directly specified the paths to my fonts.

Comment: @option_select Did you update your TeX Live recently? Try issuing `luaotfload-tool --update`

Comment: @egreg I have updated my TeX Live 2013 just today and I have run all the utilities from `tlmgr`. I'll try the tool now.

Comment: @egreg Bingo, that did the job! Thank you very much and thanks to all other commenters.

Comment: I asked in chat and @cgnieder pointed me to http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2013-July/033914.html You can write a self answer, rather than editing your question. I won't take credit for something others suggested.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This got solved due to @egreg and @cgnieder and this suggestion [tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2013-July/033914.html](http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2013-July/033914.html). If you experience similar problems, run

```
luaotfload-tool --update
```

from the command line/shell.