# MacTeX 2013 takes ages to compile

Tags: luatex, compiling, fontspec

I am sorry that this is not a very specific question.

Since I updated to 2013 I haven't been able to compile a single document. To be honest, neither did I let one of the many compilation processes I started run through in its entirety -- after 3 hours I usually gave up enervated.

Before the update, compiling took between 3 and 10 minutes (my laptop is old, too). I use `LuaLaTeX`.

Some of the steps in the process that seem to take ages:

- `(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu2enc.def`
- `(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty`
- defining? redefining? saving? doing something with the font shapes (something containing: `texlive/2013/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/brill-roman-2.luc` -- but I also tried to use standard fonts with no success)

**Update:**

I was just able to compile a document that was lacking `\usepackage{fontspec}`.

Comment: Try `luaotfload-tool --update` in the terminal (http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10248921#10248921)

Comment: see [Possible LuaLaTeX Problem (compilation seems to hang)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123164/5049)